# How to set border color in Line Chart

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have a LineChart graph. I want to color rectangular border of graph area.

"-fx-border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;" add border to x-axis or y-axis.

"-fx-border-color: black" add border around complete chart.

But i need border around graph area only as shown in attachment

Any help would be useful.[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

*Border CSS*

```
.chart-plot-background {
    -fx-border-color: red; 
    -fx-border-style: solid; 
    -fx-border-width: 4px;
    -fx-border-insets: -2px;
}
```

Gives you this:

[image: forest]

The green border around the chart plot content is what the CSS above provides.

*On dotted lines*

You will notice there are dashed lines and axes drawn on top of the green border.  Perhaps you want the border behind those lines, perhaps you want it on top, perhaps you don't want to draw those dotted lines at all.

If it is fine to have the border behind the dotted lines you don't need to do anything else.

If you don't want to draw the dotted lines, you can remove them:

```
lineChart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
lineChart.setAlternativeColumnFillVisible(false);
lineChart.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(false);
lineChart.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false);
```

and adjust the insets of your bounding rectangle accordingly:

```
.chart-plot-background {
    -fx-border-color: forestgreen; 
    -fx-border-style: solid; 
    -fx-border-width: 4px; 
    -fx-border-insets: 0 0 0 1;
}
```

[image: no lines]

If you want to keep the dotted lines and draw your rectangle on top of the chart, then you can place the chart in a StackPane, run `chart.lookup(".chart-plot-background")` after the chart has been displayed, monitor the bounds of the resultant chart background node and add a new rectangle to the top of the stack which is bound to the chart background bounds, like in this [layout bounds demo](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1441960).  You probably don't want to do that though.

*How to do this stuff yourself*

Using tools like [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) or the css analyzer in [SceneBuilder](http://gluonhq.com/products/downloads/), or studying the [CSS reference guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) or the [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/tip/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) file in the `jfxrt.jar` shipped with your JRE can help you determine the CSS rules you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can test that in your css file :

```js
/* chart background */
.chart-plot-background {
   -fx-background-color: blue;
}
/* frame background */
.chart{
   -fx-background-color: pink;
}
/* border content */
.chart-content{
  -fx-padding: 0px;
  -fx-border-color: black;
  -fx-border-width: 3px;
}
```

Comment: This is as similar to adding border to complete chart. I want to add rectangular border around graph area only. That is excluding x/y axis, legends minor/major tick of line chart. This didn't helped me

Comment: I see what you want, I tried .chart-plot or .chart-plot-border but it doesn't work, sorry.